# Magento2 update the payment method block on checkout page with knockout on one step checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

I have Magento 2.3, I want to hide the COD payment method for specific Zipcodes. For that I used the below code:

`<type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery"> <plugin name="cashondeliveryplugin" type="Xxx\Yyy\Plugin\Model\Cashondelivery" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" /> </type>`

and use the **"aroundIsAvailable"** method and it is **working fine for the one-page checkout** only. But I used this same code on **ONE STEP CHECKOUT and it is not working**. I want to refresh the payment method block after Zipcode is entered.

e.i. there are 2 payment methods available

1. COD
2. Online

When someone **enters blocked Zipcode into the postcode** field or selects the address which has blocked Zipcode, I need to **refresh the "Payment Block"** and hide the **"COD"** **payment method** and **show only the "Online" payment method**. and if **available Zipcode added then it will show both payment methods** vise versa.

please post your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not called "pincode" it's a postal code or zip . In magento2 shipping rates control what calls the reload of rates and payments https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html

Comment: Thanks, @Anton S. your given URL for the shipment validation rule I want to create the payment method validation rule. on zipcode entered or address selection. any reference regarding this will be helpful.